# jQuery, não selecionar 'child' do elemento

Tags: jquery, seletores

Eu tenho este código que faz de uma espécie de fancybox, resulta bem mas gostava que o click na imagem não fizesse desaparecer o '#overlayFancy', era bom que só o click fora da imagem é que fizesse que com este desapareça tudo, apesar de a imagem estar dentro do '#overlayFancy' que ocupa 100%*100% da janela e a imagem está a meio da janela, 500px*500px.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperExtraImg" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'admin/' .$extraImg->extra_image_path; ?>)"></div>
<div id="overlayFancy"></div>
```

js: Aparecer zoom

```
$(document).on('click', '.wrapperExtraImg' ,function(){
        var image = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#overlayFancy').stop().animate({
            "opacity":"1"
        }, 500);
        $( "#overlayFancy" ).append( "<img src="+image+">" );
});
```

js: Desaperecer, voltar para default da página

```
$(document).on('click', '#overlayFancy' ,function(){
        $('#overlayFancy').stop().animate({
            "opacity":"0",
        }, 300);
        $('#overlayFancy').children('img').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Tentou colocar a imagem em uma nova Div dentro da #overlayFancy. Tipo la no append ficaria $( "#overlayFancy" ).append( "<div><img src="+image+"></div>" );  ?

Comment: Faz o mesmo, continua a ser child do #overlayFancy

Comment: Pode explicar com outras palavras? para mim ainda está pouco claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais fácil é escutar o click na imagem e impedir a propagação, assim:

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.wrapperExtraImg', function () {
    $("#overlayFancy").append("<img src=" + $(this).attr('id') + ">").stop().fadeIn(500);
});


$(document).on('click', '#overlayFancy img', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', '#overlayFancy', function () {
    $('#overlayFancy').stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).find('img').remove();
    });
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/n9391y6x/)

Comment: Muito bem pensado, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

ao invés de usar.

```
$('#overlayFancy').children('img').remove();
```

use

```
$('#overlayFancy').html('');
```

ou então

```
$('#overlayFancy').find('img').remove();
```

Comment: Não resulta, o que quero é que ao clicar fora da imagem desapareça tudo, como tenho no ultimo js postado, mas se clicar na imagem não acontece nada

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que children() retorna uma lista (que pode ser de 1) filhos, então, possivelmente o que vocês quer é first() ou algo do tipo, pelo teu texto, não sei se as funções de hide() e show() não são melhores, que o append() e remove()